# Using Sed to Parse Base Filename into Replacement Argument

Tags: sed, basename

Working within a directory of two thousand plus of text files, I need to replace a certain string in each of those text files from "template.cmp" into "*actualfilename*". For example, for a file like mdgen.cmp, I need the original string of "template.cmp" to be changed to "mdgen".

I have tried the following command to no avail:

```
sed -i 's/template.cmp/$(basename)' ./*
```

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside single quotes, `$(basename)` is just a static string. If you want to run the command `basename`, you need double quotes, and you need to pass it an argument, or two arguments if you want to trim the extension. Guessing a bit what you are actually trying to do, something like

```sh
for file in *; do
    sed -i "s/template\.cmp/$(basename "$file" .cmp)/" "$file"
done
```

Notice also how the dot in the regex should properly be escaped with a backslash or by putting it in a character class `[.]`; an unescaped `.` matches any character at all.